# Sinatra route parameters with RegExp

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra

I am trying to make a small sinatra example that will print a calendar view for either a month, day or year depending on the URL. Such that

localhost:4567/calendar/2012        will print a year view calendar

localhost:4567/calendar/2012/9      will print a month calendar

localhost:4567/calendar/2012/9/15   will print a day view calendar

I have this working as this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/calendar/:year/:month/:day/?' do
    "printing daily calendar for #{params[:year]}/#{params[:month]}/#{params[:day]}"
end

get '/calendar/:year/:month/?' do
    "printing monthly calendar for #{params[:year]}/#{params[:month]}"
end

get '/calendar/:year/?' do
    "printing yearly calendar for #{params[:year]}"
end
```

**My question is, can I further refine those routes with some kind of RegEx so that I can say the url only counts if the :month portion is between 1 and 12 and the :day portion is between 1 and 31?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can specify regex in sinatra routing condition. See [sinatra readme](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes) for more information.

```
get %r{/calendar/([\d]+)/(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/([12][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])$} do 
  "hello #{params[:captures]}"
end

get %r{/calendar/([\d]+)/(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])$} do 
  "hello #{params[:captures]}"        
end

# host/2012/11 will print "hello [2012, 11]"
# params[:captures] will return an array containing what match the regular expressions
```

Comment: Thanks, was this answer meant to replicate my example? Because from what I can tell: host/2012/9 returns the same as host/2012/99999 and host/2012/9/15.  They all produce "hello ["2012", "9"]

Comment: @ChrisValentine There was a flaw in my old regex. The month part will match any string containing 1-12. So 99999 will match. And for `host/2012/9/15/`, there should be another route like `%r{/calendar/[\d]+/regex_for_month/regex_for_days}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me to figure it out.  As a side note do you know how to alter the regex_for_year portion to only accept positive integer values, as of now it will work if the year is 0.  Thx again.

Comment: @ChrisValentine I guess some regex like `(?<!\-)\d{4}` will work. But since maybe someone want a year like 4000 BC, it is not a bad idea to accept negative values.

Comment: Yes, that is also something to consider.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using ruby 1.9+, you can use named captures like this:

```
get %r{/(?<year>\d{4})/(?<month>\d{2})/(?<day>\d{2})/?} do
 "printing daily calendar for #{params[:year]}/#{params[:month]}/#{params[:day]}"
end

get %r{/(?<year>\d{4})/(?<month>\d{2})/?} do
  "printing monthly calendar for #{params[:year]}/#{params[:month]}"
end

get %r{/(?<year>\d{4})/?} do
  "printing monthly calendar for #{params[:year]}"
end
```